# Vertical element centering in a merged table

Tags: vertical-alignment, vertical

good morning.

How can I do the vertical centering of the p_rgh element in the table below. It is located on the 2nd row of the 1st column.

Follow the code below:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Eq. de Transporte}                                                                               & Solver                                                                                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pré-Condicionador\\ ou \emph{Smoother}\end{tabular}              & Tol.       \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$p_{-} r g h$}                                       & Modelo A                                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}PCG – Gradientes conjugados ou\\ biconjugados pré-condicionados\end{tabular}                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DIC – Diagonal Incompleta\\ de Cholesky (Simétrico)\end{tabular} & $10^{-10}$ \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                                                     & Modelo B                                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}GAMG – Solucionador multi-malha\\ geométrico-algébrico generalizado\end{tabular}                    & Gauss-Seidel (Simétrico)                                                                    & $10^{-08}$ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\emph{U}, \emph{T}, $\kappa$, $\varepsilon$, $\omega$ e \emph{R} \end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}PBiCGStab – Gradientes\\ conjugados ou biconjugados pré-\\ condicionados estabilizados\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DILU – Diagonal\\ Incompleta – LU\\ (Assimétrica)\end{tabular}   & $10^{-10}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Use `\multirow{3}{*}{…}`. However , note your table is too wide for the default layout.

Comment: @Silvio please have a look at the answer below if it suits the requirement

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to set up your table *and answer your specific question* is the `nicematrix` package, which allows you to spend more time on the table's content than on its formatting. For this table it is the only necessary package.

1. Offers the `\Block` command that replaces `multicolumn`, `multirow` and the like. `\Block{2-1}{<content>}` places the content, centered vertically and horizontally, in a 2 row x 1 column cell. No manual adjustments are needed.
2. The same command allows using `\\` inside the cell to insert new lines where it is convenient. This explains the use of the command `\Block{}{<content>}` a 1x1  cell centered  with `\\` inside.
3. Allows global directives to vertically expand all cells and draw all lines at the same time, respecting the defined blocks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[cell-space-limits=7pt, % expand the cells                            
                            hvlines]  % draw all  lines
\Block{1-2}{Eq. de Transporte}  &           & Solver                                                                    &\Block{}{Pré-Condicionador\\ ou \emph{Smoother}}               & Tol.             \\   
\Block{2-1}{$p_{-} r g h$}      & Modelo A  & \Block{}{PCG – Gradientes conjugados ou\\ biconjugados pré--condicionados}&\Block{}{DIC – Diagonal Incompleta\\ de Cholesky (Simétrico)}  & $10^{-10}$ \\
                                &  Modelo B & \Block{}{GAMG – Solucionador multi--malha\\ geométrico--algébrico generalizado}&  Gauss-Seidel (Simétrico)                                & $10^{-08}$       \\
\Block{1-2}{\emph{U}, \emph{T}, $\kappa$, $\varepsilon$, $\omega$ e \emph{R}} &  &\Block{}{PBiCGStab – Gradientes\\ conjugados ou biconjugados \\pré--condicionados estabilizados}   &\Block{}{DILU – Diagonal\\ Incompleta – LU\\ (Assimétrica)}  & $10^{-10}$ \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}   
    
\end{document}
```

As you can see the code is more compact, so it is much easier to maintain or rearrange the content.

The package manual is full of examples to show its possibilities. It uses Tikz nodes, so a couple of builds are needed the first time.

Comment: You can use `cell-space-limits=7pt` to fix both `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedbak. I updated the asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

You can further fine tune the location of multirow by using 3.1 or 3.2

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, multirow, booktabs, makecell}
%\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
%\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}

    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Eq. de Transporte} 
        &Solver  
            &\makecell[c]{Pré--Condicionador\\ ou \emph{Smoother}} 
                &Tol.                                               \\ \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{$p_{-} r g h$}
        & Modelo A
            & \makecell[c]{PCG – Gradientes conjugados ou\\ biconjugados pré-condicionados}
                & \makecell[c]{DIC – Diagonal Incompleta\\ de Cholesky (Simétrico)}
                     & $10^{-10}$                                   \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
    & Modelo B
        & \makecell[c]{GAMG – Solucionador multi-malha\\ geométrico-algébrico generalizado}
            & Gauss-Seidel (Simétrico)
                & $10^{-08}$                                        \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\emph{U}, \emph{T}, $\kappa$, $\varepsilon$, $\omega$ e \emph{R} \end{tabular}} 
        & \makecell[c]{PBiCGStab – Gradientes\\ conjugados ou biconjugados pré-\\ condicionados estabilizados}
            &\makecell[c]{DILU – Diagonal\\ Incompleta – LU\\ (Assimétrica)}
                & $10^{-10}$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```